# how to create a Foreign-Key constraint to a subset of the rows of a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have a reference table, say `OrderType` that collects different types of orders:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OrderType (name VARCHAR);
ALTER TABLE OrderType ADD PRIMARY KEY (name);
INSERT INTO OrderType(name) VALUES('sale-order-type-1');
INSERT INTO OrderType(name) VALUES('sale-order-type-2');
INSERT INTO OrderType(name) VALUES('buy-order-type-1');
INSERT INTO OrderType(name) VALUES('buy-order-type-2');
```

I wish to create a FK constraint from another table, say `SaleInformation`, pointing to that table (`OrderType`). However, I am trying to express that not all rows of `OrderType` are eligible for the purposes of that FK (it should only be sale-related order types).

I thought about creating a view of table `OrderType` with just the right kind of rows (view `SaleOrderType`) and adding a FK constraint to that view, but PostgreSQL balks at that with:

```
ERROR: referenced relation "SaleOrderType" is not a table
```

So it seems I am unable to create a FK constraint to a view (why?). Am I only left with the option of creating a redundant table to hold the sale-related order types? The alternative would be to simply allow the FK to point to the original table, but then I am not really expressing the constraint as strictly as I would like to.

Comment: What about having OrderType structure like: id_order_type as serial(pk), order_type as character varying, type_order_type character varying:  and reference id_order_type from SaleInformation ??

Comment: Edit your question, and paste the CREATE TABLE statement for OrderType, please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your schema should be something like this

```
create table order_nature (
    nature_id int primary key,
    description text
);
insert into order_nature (nature_id, description)
values (1, 'sale'), (2, 'buy')
;

create table order_type (
    type_id int primary key,
    description text
);
insert into order_type (type_id, description)
values (1, 'type 1'), (2, 'type 2')
;

create table order_nature_type (
    nature_id int references order_nature (nature_id),
    type_id int references order_type (type_id),
    primary key (nature_id, type_id)
);

insert into order_nature_type (nature_id, type_id)
values (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)
;

create table sale_information (
    nature_id int default 1 check (nature_id = 1),
    type_id int,
    foreign key (nature_id, type_id) references order_nature_type (nature_id, type_id)
);
```

If the `foreign key` clause would also accept an expression the sale information could omit the nature_id column

```
create table sale_information (
    type_id int,
    foreign key (1, type_id) references order_nature_type (nature_id, type_id)
);
```

Notice the `1` in the `foreign key`

Comment: In case of omiting `nature_id` column from `sale_information` table how can make a FK with two columns? Something like this seems more correct to me: `foreign key (type_id) references order_nature_type (1, type_id)` or `foreign key (type_id) references order_nature_type (type_id) where [order_nature_type].nature_id = 1` Only I'm not sure if they work. How can accomplish something like that?

Comment: A variant on the FK + check constraint idea: if `order_nature` and `order_type` are not very large tables, `order_nature_type` could have a single ID column whose value would be `nature_id *` _some_ _constant_ `+  type_id`.  The check constraint could do division or a bitwise `AND` to retrieve the `nature_id` from the combined ID.

Yes, it's a bit homely.  But I'm facing something similar and it's the least homely thing I've come up with so far.  And the alternative (an ever growing proliferation of dozens of tiny tables) is an annoyance that's gradually turning into a nightmare.

Comment: This works in MS SQL Server as well, with some minor syntax changes

Answer (score 3):

You could use an FK to `OrderType` to ensure referential integrity and a separate CHECK constraint to limit the order types.

If your `OrderType` values really are that structured then a simple CHECK like this would suffice:

```
check (c ~ '^sale-order-type-')
```

where `c` is order type column in `SaleInformation`

If the types aren't structured that way in reality, then you could add some sort of type flag to `OrderType` (say a boolean `is_sales` column), write a function which uses that flag to determine if an order type is a sales order:

```
create or replace function is_sales_order_type(text ot) returns boolean as $$
    select exists (select 1 from OrderType where name = ot and is_sales);
$$ language sql
```

and then use that in your CHECK:

```
check(is_sales_order_type(c))
```

You don't of course have to use a boolean `is_sales` flag, you could have more structure than that, `is_sales` is just for illustrative purposes.